# Getting a return value via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have a python script which I'm calling from within a form using a button and some javascript with ajax. I'm really struggling to get to the returned variable which the python script returns.

The information which is getting returned all seems to be happening in the wrong order, which is probably not the case but its how it looks to me. All I want is to be able to get the data which my python script returns. How can something so simple be so hard!!

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
            <script>
            function drawgraph() {
                    var x = draw()
                    alert(x)
            };
            </script>
            <script>
            function draw() {
                    alert("Hello");
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/currentcost.py",
                            success: function(response){
                            alert("Success");
                            return response;
                            //here you do whatever you want with the response variable
                            }
                    });
                    alert("World");
            }
            </script>
```

The responses I get are "Hello", "World", "Undefined" and "Success"

This says to me the ajax function isn't actually completing until AFTER my javascript function has finished which doesn't help me actually get hold of the returned variable so I can use it in the javascript later on

Chris

EDIT.

```
    <head>
            <title>Line Chart</title>
            <script>
            var ajaxResponse = ""
            </script>
            <script src="Chart.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
                    function drawgraph() {
                            function handleResponse(response) {
                                    ajaxResponse = response;
                            }
                            draw(handleResponse);
                    };

                    function draw(handleResponse) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "/currentcost.py",
                    success: function(response){
                            handleResponse(response);
                    }
                    });
            }
            </script>
            <script>
                    function alertbox() {
                            alert(ajaxResponse);
                    }
            </script>
```

Currentcost.py:

import MySQLdb

def index(req):
    dtbox = req.form.getfirst('dt', '')
    tmbox = req.form.getfirst('tm', '')

```
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    s = "SELECT tmp, watts FROM currentcost WHERE dt ='" + dtbox + "' and tm like '" + tmbox + "%'"
    cur.execute (s)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    x=""
    y=""
    for row in rows:
        x=x+row["watts"]+","
        y=y+row["tmp"]+","

x="data:["+x+"]"
y="data:["+y+"]"

con.close()

req.write(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. When you alert `x` it will most likely be `undefined` because the ajax response is not received yet, or ajax is not even started. Pass a callback function that can handle the response, instead of returning it :

```js
//global variable holding the response
//substitutes your x
var ajaxResponse;

function drawgraph() {
    function handleResponse(response) {
        ajaxResponse = response; 
        //here you may want to do something with the response
        //like calling a function that uses the global variable ajaxResponse

        //alert(response);
    }
    draw(handleResponse);
};

function draw(handleReponse) {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/currentcost.py",
       success: function(response){
           handleResponse(response);
       }
    });
}
```

### Edit

In my little test I just called drawgraph in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  drawgraph();
}
```

Eg, on page load. Once. It was onclear how you wanted to trigger it. If click on a button, and the button `id` is "button", `<button id="button">click</button>`

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  drawgraph();
}
```

Chain of execution :

1. something calls drawgraph
2. drawgraph calls draw and passes a callback function
3. on ajax success, the callback function is called with the response

Because javascript is asynchronous, you have to "wait" before you can "carry on with the rest of the code", and the best way is to continue execution from inside $.ajax success.

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone, its all new to me so rather than rush an paste the code examples and get into a bigger mess I'll do some reading and find out where I'm going wrong!

Comment: Well, its kind of working. I do indeed get the data returned but I expected an alert box to come up with the data where as infact a whole new page is spawned. Of course I was hoping to eventually replace the alert box with a variable and carry on with the rest of the code (which works). Could I trouble you to explain what is happening above please? I can see my form calls draw() but what calls draw graph()? In fact if anything called drawgraph() it would appear to go into an endless loop calling and calling draw(). sorry, I'm completely lost :-( I'm also using an iframe in the form.

Comment: Many many thanks. I'm still struggling however. Basically I will be firing 3 of these sets of functions off to collect data from an external DB. The idea was to add them to a global variable which I could use when I drew the chart. I have taken the step of defining all the global vars at the start of the HTML page just inside the hearer (<script> var x=""; </script>. So, each time I run the functions above I simply do as suggested and save to one of the vars. Adding a button to the form with alert(myVar) however simply comes back with blank! I've editted the script in my original post

Comment: @Dave I'm getting closer now, found a couple of typo's which I corrected above. All I'm getting back is Data[] suggesting there are no records, however, if I return back s and not x from the python script the select statement has no dates in which are picked up from the form field. This suggests the python script for some reason isn't reading the form fields. If I submit the form with the action equal to my python script I get a new page with the correct data in!! So, it looks like I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

That's the nature of asynchronous programming. It's non-blocking. You have to initiate the execution of the code that requires the `response` within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The "A" in Ajax is asynchronous.  This means that the HTTP request is done and the rest of your JS code executes.  You can't depend on *when* the request will complete or even *if* it will complete.  Any work that depends on the value returned from the request has to be done in the callback (`success`)

```
function (response) {
    alert("Success");
    // this will alert the response
    alert(response);
}
```

Moreover, the `return` from the callback does not go anywhere.  You do not return from `draw` either.

You could use deferred to make the syntax more palatable:

```
function drawgraph() {
    var x = draw();
    x.done(function (response) {
        alert(x);
    });
}
function draw() {
    return $.ajax(/* your code */
```