# AJAX callback function not executing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**EDIT** Turns out it was a simple misspelling. ugh.

Problem (Please refer to the following code): When I click on the button, the sample text turns blue (meaning it successfully runs the python script). However, when I comment out `$("#test").css("color", "blue");`, the text does not turn red, which I believe would imply the callback function is not being called. What am I missing?

```
<p id="test">ayyo testo</p>

<button onclick="validate()" value="checkvalue" type="button" class="button">Listen</button>

<script type="application/javascript"> 

    $('button').click(function(){
      drawgraph();
    });

   function drawgraph() {
     function handleResponse(response) {
         $("#test").css("color", "red");
     }
     drawStuff(handleResponse);
   };


    function drawStuff(handleReponse) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "testPython.py",
        success: function(response){
            $("#test").css("color", "blue");
            handleResponse(response);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Associated to the button you have `onclick="validate()"`. You don't have this function. This will produce you an error in the console. Please check the console.

Comment: anything in the **developer** tools console, such as an error?

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I removed it but it still exhibits the same behavior. @quirimmo

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with python. By tagging it as python, you are only keeping away the best javascript minds

Comment: Why are you killing yourself by naming a function, a parameter and a callback all as `handleResponse`? Trying to identify the scope gave me a headache

Comment: ok, I misspelled handleResponse when it was passed into drawStuff. Thanks for the suggestion to look at dev tools! (if you want to make it an answer I'll can accept it)

Comment: @e4c5 you're right, my mistake. Also I got that code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947994/getting-a-return-value-via-ajax) stackOverflow solution

Comment: No worries, as long as it's sorted out and you are on your way, I am good. :)